# Laravel Nova : page won't refresh following Ajax query

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Nova as the admin panel of my web app. When navigating through the admin, the URL is updated when I click on menu or resource for example, but the page is not refreshed. When I look into the debug bar, I can see that an Ajax query is issued but nothing happens then. If I click on the URL bar and hit enter, the page loads properly. This only happens on the admin (Nova) side and not on the public side.

Would you have any idea on what could be the root cause ? Any aspect I should investigate ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately not really. I ended up updating every module and it fixed the issue but I couldn’t find out where the problem was.